# Are the East Asian language packs included with Windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008

On our Citrix XenApp farm running on Windows 2003, we had to manually install the optional East Asian languages. This option in control panel is no longer present in Windows 2008 upon which we are building a new XenApp image. I wondered if they are bundled in Windows 2008 as they are in Windows Vista as mentioned in this article?

http://sharemypoint.in/2011/03/29/sharepoint-2010-language-pack-installing-support-for-east-asian-languages/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're just wanting to be sure?

Do you have a particular keyboard language in mind?

This is from one of my 2008 R2 servers, yes they are included.

[image]

Comment: Yes - just wanting to check as don't have easy way to confirm. The original request to install the East Asian languages came from years ago when somebody needed to display Asian characters in Internet Explorer. The term "Asian languages" was a bit vague bit one assumes that it included Chinese

Comment: I guess if I went to a website that used East Asian characters I would be able to totally confirm